# What kind of conditions we need to make morphisms of schemes quasi-projective?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, schemes

What kind of conditions we need to make morphisms of schemes quasi-projective?

I am really interested in the following case:

If $f : X \to Y$ is an etale, of finite type and separated morphism of schemes, then is it quasi-projective?

If so, which conditions we use?

If necessary, please assume that the scheme $Y$ is locally noetherian.

Comment: A quasi-projective morphism of locally Noetherian schemes is of finite type, so that should be a hypothesis as well.

Comment: Oh, you are right! I will edit the condition. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is yes, if you assume that $Y$ is quasi-compact, and $f:X\to Y$ is of finite type and separated.

Every etale morphism is unramified, which implies it is quasi-finite (Milne, Prop 3.2).  This in turn implies by Zariski's main theorem (Milne, Thm 1.8), that $f$ factors as an open immersion followed by a finite map.  Hence $f$ is quasi-affine, hence quasi-projective.

The reference is Milne: Etale cohomology.